# Turn off reading zip archives in browser

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

I've recently learned that QGIS Browser Panel is able to read zip archives.

Unfortunately when there's a large archive (let's say 10GB) in a folder the browser is forced to scan it's contents. This prevents display of the folder's content until the scan is finished.

Is there a way to turn off zip archive read by the Browser Panel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In QGIS, go to the `Settings / Options...` menu, then choose `Data Sources` and disable zip files scanning.

[image: No Zip scan]

Comment: Do you know what the difference between "Full scan" and "Basic scan" is?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto There is a note in the source code "Using (Full Scan) will ignore invalid items. Using (Basic Scan) would raise errors". I honestly haven't seen a difference between the two.

Comment: Ha! Must have had an episode of temporal blindness, because I searched options a few times. Thanks for that!